# Direct download for chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a way we can let user install an extension directly from the website rather than having user to redirect chrome store every time?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. This method is called Inline Installation, you can read about it here [Using Inline Installation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation).

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.** Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).